# Heavy traffic in Taiwan during New Year's Day?

Tags: public-holidays, taiwan, traffic

I have plan to go to Taiwan January 1st, 2016.
My friends and I want to go to Tailuge (Taroko) national park. We decided to do taxi tour from Taipei to Tailuge (Taroko), and I have question here.

Is there going to be heavy traffic jam to get to Hualian province? 
I am kinda worried because it's a holiday for the Taiwan people too.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Traffic levels shouldn't be any different than any other weekend in Taipei. If you leave early enough, you should be ok. However, I suggest taking the train instead. It's much cheaper (~NT440, ~$12) and you don't have to deal with traffic. Once you get there, you can rent a scooter (for around NT500) to get around.